# structure member syntax

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, struct

I am unable to access member of a structure

The code is as follows :

```
int main()
{

      typedef struct tempA
       {
         int a;
        }tempa;


      typedef struct tempB
      {
        tempa **tA;
       }tempb;

     tempb.(*tA)->a =5;
     printf("\n Value of a : %d",tempb.(*tA)->a);

}
```

I tried to access it using  `tempb.(*tA)->a;` but I am getting syntax error:

> ```
> error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
> ```

What is the correct syntax to access `int a`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code contains multiple errors, including: missing parameter list for main(), missing return (unless you're using a C99 compiler), and more importantly, there is no variable named tempb.  Please post code that actually compiles, unless the question is "why does this code not compile".

Comment: I read too quickly, the question is indeed "why does this not compile" - but you are still trying to access a variable which does not exist.

Answer (score 7):

The right syntax is `(*tempb.tA)->a`. You want to dereference `tempb.tA` to get a pointer to a `tempA`, then dereference that pointer to access the `a` member.

Comment: Hi,  What if I try to access te same thing with a pointer to tempb What will be the syntax tempb *tB  tB->(*tA)->a I tried but its not working

Comment: Then it's `(*tempb->tA)->a` - you dereference tempb to access the tA member, and from there on it's the same as before. If you prefer, you could also write that as `(*(tempb->tA))->a`, but since the dereferencing operator `*` is applied after `.` and `->`, it's not actually necessary.